# Django authentication login page modification

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I created a django project with many applications inside that projects, All of the applications make use of the same login page.
How can I get the login page to read data from a particular application's view so that the database can provide data which would be viewed inside
the login page.

So I can do something like this.

```
datadict = {'datafromdatabase': dataFromDatabase}
response = render(request,'loginapplication/login_page.html', datadict)
return response
```

Comment: Use the `view.py` on the project layer if it's used in all applications. If you want to use a particular applications models then import it from this file.

Comment: @Lewis please can u expantiate a little more on it

Comment: As you're creating aView which is generic and doesn't apply to a single application. It would be better store in `<project>/views.py` rather than `<project>/<app>/views.py`.

Comment: @Lewis. In my application I send data from view through `return render(request,
     'applicationname/template.html',
     {'item1':arrayData,
    'item2':arrayData2})`. How can i do the above from the project level since it is not looking up an app